# Show a media attribute

Tags: php, attributes, media

I've created a media attribute, and now i'm triyng to display this attribute to my product view page.

I've tried this code below:

```
$hdr_img = $cur_product->getResource()->getAttribute('header_img');
if ($hdr_img)
{
    $ban_img = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($cur_product, 'header_img')->resize(1600, 312);
    echo $ban_img;
}
```

But all I got is a :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getResource()
>   on unknown in
>   /var/www/virtual/unikamakeup.com/htdocs/app/design/frontend/sns_simo/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:132
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/virtual/unikamakeup.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
>   include() #1
>   /var/www/virtual/unikamakeup.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/sns_si...') #2
>   /var/www/virtual/unikamakeup.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView() #3
>   /var/www/virtual/unikamakeup.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml() #4
>   /var/www/virtual/unikamakeup.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() #5
>   /var/www/virtual/unikamakeup.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml() #6
>   /var/www/virtual/unikamakeup.com/htdocs/app/code/core/ in
>   /var/www/virtual/unikamakeup.com/htdocs/app/design/frontend/sns_simo/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
>   on line 132

Answer (score 0):

$cur_product is undefined.  Says so right there in the stack trace. You need to make sure that $cur_product is actually set to something before you try to access any methods on it.

You might include the code that defines $cur_product so we may better assist you.

Additionally, a nice way to check if your product is valid is doing this:

```
var_dump($cur_product->debug());
```

or

```
var_dump($cur_product->getData());
```

This will output a mostly human readable array of the current variable's data.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: The question was hardly a complete question, but I let THAT slide.

Answer (score -1):

Its Working code and i tested in my magento 1.9.2.2

> $hdr_img = $_product->getHeaderImg();
>
> ```
> if ($hdr_img)
>
> {
>
> $ban_img = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'header_img')->resize(1600, 312);
>
> echo $ban_img;
>
> }
> ```

Have you assigned image for the given media attribute in images tab in Manage product section.